# How to communicate with an external server using django application?

Tags: django

Currently I have a requirement,I need to communicate with external server using django application. The server is already up,Next section is the data transfer. I need some time samples and values from server and I need to send responses back to server. How django port can listen to external server.? How it can response back? I need asynchronous communication and REST responses

Comment: What exactly is the external server? Does it run an HTTP server too?

Comment: External server is a postgres db which is a game server and totally independent of django application. Djnago application has a sqlite db and I need communication between this game server db and django application db.  @AKX

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the external server is a PostgreSQL database.

Since you're using Django, you can easily set this up as a secondary database in your settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': # that SQLite config...,
    'game': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'somewhere-else',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

You don't have to [route any models to that database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example), but if you do create any models to correspond to the data in the game server, [you'll want to set `managed = False` so Django doesn't do migrations or anything](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#managed).

If you don't want to use models, just [open a cursor to the secondary database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-raw-cursors-with-multiple-databases) and [query away](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```py
from django.db import connections
with connections['game'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT something FROM some_table')
    # etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to know the time samples and values of an external db by adding multiple db in django settings.py? Since Iam new to django , these are new knowledge for me..

Comment: You can do anything with the external database, that's not Django's concern. Even if you were using a database that's not directly supported by Django, you could just use its native connection drivers.

Comment: Thanks, I have a doubt in this................Do I need to use django channels for this process?,since my application need a continuous time samples from the external db..

Comment: If you need to pipe the time samples to the client in realtime, yes, you'd need some realtime process, be it Django Channels or something else.